# How to change &#2404; again into "।" that is Hindi Full Stop Character (Purnviram)

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, html-entities, html-encode, htmlspecialchars

This block of code gives me code `&#2404;` instead of "।", so how to change `&#2404;` again into "।". "।" is Hindi Full Stop Character known as Purnviram. This code works fine to convert dot(.) into "।" but on blogger.com, it fails to convert(.) into Purnviram(।)/Danda/Small pipe/a Hindi language special character. see [Link](https://yyyuuyuyjujuj.blogspot.com/2021/10/ffbvf-fb-df-f.html) I have added the save code on the link

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
          $('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var str = val.replace('.', '।');
            $(this).val(str);
          });
        });
</script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: It works here but fails on blogger platform [Link](https://yyyuuyuyjujuj.blogspot.com/2021/10/ffbvf-fb-df-f.html). check the link and press the dot key (.) in textarea, it gives &#2404; instead of "।".

Comment: I guess it may happen 'cause jQuery `.val()` internal logic. Plain JS `input.value = '।' // or str` works fine for me.

Comment: @Xeelley
Please write the complete code, I don't have much knowledge of coding

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec
Please have a look at issues on the above code

Comment: This is not a jQuery problem; it's something that the Blogger platform is doing deliberately. The code you have should be correct (well, it **is** correct).

Comment: @Pointy
Thank you sir for your reply. Is there any solution for it? I'm not an expert in javascript.  I am trying to achieve the desired output for more than one month but did not get the appropriate solution

Comment: I don't know; I have no idea why code on the Blogger site would do things like that; it may be some kind of misguided or inadequate security measure.

Comment: Something that might be worth trying is to wrap the `.val()` call that "fixes" the textarea in a timeout to update the value 20 or 30 milliseconds after the "keyup" event.

Comment: @Pointy
Can I convert &#2404; into "।" again using javascript function in the same code

Comment: Well you could, but to me it's extremely strange that the Blogger code is doing that at all.

Comment: @Pointy
Please write the code to convert &#2404; into "।" again that work on blogger

Comment: @Pointy
Please edit in the above code

Comment: Well the problem is that Blogger may perform that transformation repeatedly.

Comment: @Pointy
When I check the source code of the blogger page, we found there var str = val.replace('.', ' &#2404;'); instead of var str = val.replace('.', '।'); but when we use another symmbol like pipe in var str = val.replace('.', '|'); it does not change and get | instead of html code

Comment: How exactly are you including the script code in the Blogger page?

Comment: You could try `var str = val.replace('.', String.fromCharCode(2404));` to perform the replacement; the Blogger code might not notice that.

Comment: @Pointy
Thank you a lot Sir, a million thanks to you. It works fine here [link](https://xsajxbjkls.blogspot.com/2021/11/bm-lm.html)

Comment: @Pointy 
Sir, Is it possible to shift this "।" a place left in the same code. Now I want to shift  "।" a place left after pressing the dot(.) converting into "।"

Comment: I see `var str = val.replace('.', '&#2404;');` in source of your [link](https://yyyuuyuyjujuj.blogspot.com/2021/10/ffbvf-fb-df-f.html) at line 2652; hence, it works as imposed by your own code…

Comment: @JosefZ I think that encoding is imposed when the script is included via the Blogger editor.

Comment: Well you could `.replace(/(.)\./, String.fromCharCode(2404) + "$1")`, but trying to process actual text in *any* language can get very complicated.

Comment: @Pointy Sir,
A million thanks once again, I got the desired result by 
var str = val.replace(/(.)\./, String.fromCharCode(2404) + "$1");

Comment: @JosefZ
Thank you Sir for the suggestion

Comment: @Pointy Sir, If we need to insert  " . " in textarea I have created a button with function but it also convert in purnviraam, Please help
<script>
function myFunction1() {
    insertfullstop.data.value+='.';
 document.getElementById("data").focus();
}
</script>  

<tr align="right">
<td style="padding-top: 5px; float='center' padding-left: 1px; " colspan="1"><strong style="font-size: 16px;"></strong> <button id="fullstop" OnClick="myFunction1()" class="btn1" title="Full Stop" type="button">.</button> </td>
</tr>
[link](https://xsajxbjkls.blogspot.com/2021/11/bm-lm.html)

Comment: @Pointy Sir, The above code insert (.) but when press shift it convert into purnviram(।) for which we already have added the code